# Why Dataframe.groupby.sum() is not showing the aggregated values?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_agency = pd.read_excel("Sample.xlsm")
```

[image]

```
data_agency.groupby(['Person']).sum()
```

But I get something similar to only a single row's of data instead:
[image]

`type(data_agency['Person'].iloc[0])` returns a `str` type

`type(data_agency['Reg Hrs.'].iloc[0])` returns a `float64` type

Comment: what you are expecting ?

Comment: I was hoping to get the sums of each column under the name of `Julius Balderas`. So `Reg Hrs.` should be `30.25` for instance

Comment: Okay sorry for the confusion guys. Apparently I just pressed restart kernel and re-run notebook and it worked. Perhaps I overwrote the dataframe :/ flagged for deletion

Comment: What is the result of `data_agency.dtypes.value_counts()`?

Comment: Yup sorry i'm new to python. I don't know I somehow touched the dataframe while playing around lol. Didn't think of re-running the whole set of codes until after I posted. First time to raise a flag I used to be able just delete instantly but after answers are posted need to flag for deletion now

Answer (score 0):

you can select those columns and then apply aggregation

```
data_agency.groupby(['Person'])[["LunchBreak", "HoursWorked", "Regofhours","RegNSDHrs","RegOTNSDHRS"]].sum()
```

Comment: Apparently I get the same values here just the single 7 digit it does not sum up

Comment: @Pherdindy i think you have problem in data type of column so please check the data type

Answer (score 0):

```
data_agency.groupby('Person').agg('sum')
```

Comment: Same issue it does not sum up oddly

Comment: Try doing:  data_agency['Hours Worked']=data_agency['Hours Worked'].astype(float)